# Where am I misunderstanding this eigenvalue problem

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I am really frustrated because I cant for the life of me understand at all where my mistake is.

For the matrix $$A= \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ -4 & 0 \\ \end{pmatrix}$$

I calculated the characteristic polynomial to be $\lambda^{2}+4$

which gives me two eigenvalues,

$\lambda_{1}=2i $

and $\lambda_{2}=-2i$

So then I trying solving for the eigenvectors,

for my first Eigen value I start with

$$\begin{pmatrix} -2i & 1 \\ -4 & -2i \\ \end{pmatrix}$$

I divide the first row by $-1/2i$ and divide the second row by $-1/4$

leads to

$$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & -1/2i \\ 1 & 1/2i \\ \end{pmatrix}$$

not subtracting row 1 from row 2 gives

$$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & -1/2i \\ 0 & 1/i \\ \end{pmatrix}$$

Which further can be simplified to the identity matrix by simple algebra.

So then I am stuck because that implies we have the non existent Eigen vector $0$, which isn't the case as I am told that the solution is actually $v=(-i/2,1)$

and I don't understand how.

Where is my mistake? I thought I did the rules correct. It must be in my algebra?

Can anyone help for me to understand?

Thanks

Comment: Not sure why you start with the matrix you say you start with.  Instead, try:
$$
\lambda_{1} [x_{1} \; x_{2}]^T = A [x_{1} \; x_{2}]^T = [x_{2} \; -4 x_{1}].
$$
This gives us:
$$
\lambda_{1} x_{1} = x_{2}, \quad \lambda_{1} x_{2} = -4 x_{1}.
$$

Comment: @user8960 The OP is starting with $A-\lambda I$ for $\lambda=2i$. This step is correct since the null space of this matrix is an eigenspace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not formatting your numbers properly and thus confusing yourself. This matrix:
$$\begin{bmatrix}1 & -1/2i \\ 1 & 1/2i\end{bmatrix}$$
Should actually be like this:
$$\begin{bmatrix}1 & \frac{-1}{2i} \\ 1 & \frac{1}{2}i\end{bmatrix}$$
Now, simplify the first row using $\frac{1}{i}=-i$:
$$\begin{bmatrix}1 & \frac{1}{2}i \\ 1 & \frac{1}{2}i\end{bmatrix}$$
Now, it is easy to see that this matrix is singular, as it should be.

Comment: Thanks for finding my mistake. now it makes sense.